# read word from each row in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sklearn-pandas

I want to read the word "risk" from every row in dataframe. If a row have the word risk in it then the dataframe should make a new column which will put 1 in it else 0. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of a pythonic way. but i think this is what youre looking for

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['hello risk', 'hello there', 'hi']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample data':data})


findrisk = [str(i).find("risk") for i in df['Sample data']]
check=[]
for i in findrisk:
    if i >= 0:
        i = 1
    else:
        i = 0
    check.append(i)

df['result'] = check
```